# Making telephone call from ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a requirement that we need to make a telephone call using ASP.NET application.

Our ASP.NET application is used in call center. Currently, they make a call to customer manually. Now, the call should go from our application by clicking the phone number link and starts recording the conversation between the agent (application user) and customer.

1. What all would be the hardware requirements for the above scenario?
2. How can we implement telephone calling in asp.net application and what are the required components to implement the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use phone line you should use Computer-telephony boards, for example Dialogic: http://www.dialogic.com/products/ip_enabled/ip_boards.htm They should have API, so you will be able to use it from your application.

Answer (score 3):

Nexmo offers a range of cloud communication APIs including [Voice API](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/overview) that allows you to fulfil this requirement.

All you need is to install the Nuget package:

```
Install-Package Nexmo.Csharp.Client
```

Then use the Call class:

```
Call.Do(new Call.CallCommand
{
 to = new[]
  {
     new Call.Endpoint 
     {
        type = "phone",
        number = NEXMO_TO_NUMBER
     }
  from = new Call.Endpoint
     {
        type = "phone",
        number = NEXMO_FROM_NUMBER
     },
 answer_url = new[]
     {
        NEXMO_CALL_ANSWER_URL
     }
});
```

Here's a detailed post on [how to make a phone call with Nexmo Voice API and ASP.Net](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/07/28/text-to-speech-phone-call-dr/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Asterisk, you might also consider Twilio, a web based telephony service that provides you a rest based api for making and receiving phone calls. See http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/ for info.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use Third party API To Make a Call Using Asp.net Code.First You Need To Register.  Here's a detailed post on

[How To Make a Call Using Asp.net Code](https://techmafiadevelopers.blogspot.in/2018/04/how-to-make-call-using-aspnet-code.html)

protected void btnCall_click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

         // Call porcessing happens here.



        // Use your account SID and authentication token instead of

        // the placeholders shown here.

        var accountSID = "C0d09f4042d1ff4acb55329cf8e5efb";

        var authToken = "05b278c6f3538d3a35f13b25c73dff";



        // Instantiate an instance of the Twilio client.

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSID, authToken);



        // Retrieve the account, used later to retrieve the

        var account = AccountResource.Fetch(accountSID);



       // this.varDisplay.Items.Clear();







            // Retrieve the values entered by the user.

            var To =new PhoneNumber(txtMobileNumber.Text);

        //twlio=14155992671

            var from = new PhoneNumber("+918098641075");

            var myMessage = this.txtMessage.Text;



            // Create a URL using the Twilio message and the user-entered

            // text. You must replace spaces in the user's text with '%20'

            // to make the text suitable for a URL.

            var url = @"http://twimlets.com/message?Message%5B0%5D={myMessage.Replace()}";

            var twimlUri = new Uri(url);



            // Display the endpoint, API version, and the URL for the message.

            this.varDisplay.Items.Add(@"Using Twilio endpoint { }");

            this.varDisplay.Items.Add(@"Twilioclient API Version is {apiVersion}");

            this.varDisplay.Items.Add(@"The URL is {url}");



            // Place the call.

             var Call=CallResource.Create(To,from,url:twimlUri);

           // var call = CallResource.create(to, from, url: twimlUri);

            this.varDisplay.Items.Add("Call status: " + Call.Status);





    }
```